# Evaluate the integral $\int x^{\frac{-4}{3}}(-x^{\frac{2}{3}}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$x^{\frac{-4}{3}}(-x^{\frac{2}{3}}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{(-\sqrt[3]{x^2}+1)}}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}}$$

Is it necessary to simplify the function further? What substitution is useful?

$u=\sqrt[n]{\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}}$ doesn't work.

Comment: The "rationalizing substitution"  $ \ u \ = \ x^{1/3} \ \Rightarrow \ u^3 \ = \ x \ \Rightarrow \ 3 \ u^2 \ du \ = \ dx \ $ could be of value, followed by a trigonometric substitution.  (A substitution based on  $ \ u \ = \ x^{2/3}  \ $ also works.)

Comment: Nice question..............+1

Comment: It is a curious property of the anti-derivative obtained by either **Claude Leibovici**  [which comes out as  $$ -3\sin^{-1}(  x^{1/3 }) \ - \ 3 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{-2/3}}}{x^{1/3}} \ + \ C \ \ ] $$  or by **Harish Chandra Rajpoot** (which differs only by a numerical constant) that the function is **non-positive** over its domain $ \ (0, \ 1] \ $ .  This proves to be connected with the fact that the integrand, which is positive, gives a _divergent_ improper integral $ \  \int_0^1 \  x^{\frac{-4}{3}}(-x^{\frac{2}{3}}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} \ \ dx \ $ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in RecklessReckoner's comment, let us first change variable $x=u^3$ then $dx=3u^2du$. So, $$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2/3}}}{x^{4/3}}dx=3\int\frac{ \sqrt{1-u^2}}{u^2}du$$ Now, $u=\sin(t)$, $du=\cos(t)\,dt$ makes $$I=3\int  \cot ^2(t)\,dt=3\int \frac{1-\sin^2(t)}{\sin^2(t)}dt =3\Big(\int \frac{dt}{\sin^2(t)}-\int dt \Big)=-3 \big(t+\cot (t)\big)$$ For sure, we could have saved a step with a single change of variable $x=\sin^3(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\int x^{-4/3}\left(-x^{2/3}+1\right)^{1/2}\ dx$$$$=\int \frac{1}{x}\left(-x^{2/3}+1\right)^{1/2}(x^{-1/3}\ dx)$$

Let $-x^{2/3}+1=\sin^2\theta\implies -\frac{2}{3}x^{-1/3}\ dx=2\sin\theta\cos\theta\ d\theta$ or $x^{-1/3}\ dx=-3\sin\theta\cos\theta\ d\theta $
$$=\int\frac{1}{(1-\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}}(\sin\theta)(-3\sin\theta\cos\theta\ d\theta )$$
$$=-3\int\frac{\sin^2\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^3\theta}\ d\theta$$
$$=-3\int\tan^2\theta\ d\theta$$
$$=-3\int(\sec^2\theta-1)\ d\theta$$

$$=-3(\tan\theta-\theta)+C$$
$$=3\theta-3\tan\theta+C$$
substituting back the value of $\theta$, 
$$=\color{red}{3\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{1-x^{2/3}}) \ - \ 3 \frac{\sqrt{x^{-2/3}-1}}{x^{1/3}} \ + \ C}$$

Comment: There is one small problem in your "back-substitution" for $ \ \tan \theta \  $ , which I have edited (you omitted the denominator).

Answer (score 0):

Following RecklessReckoner's comment:

We have $\int x^{\frac{-4}{3}}(-x^{\frac{2}{3}}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm dx$.

Now, let $u=x^{1/3}$ and $3u \mathrm du=\mathrm dx$

This gives $3\int u^{-4}(-u^{2}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}u\mathrm du=3\int u^{-3}(-u^{2}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm du=3\int u^{-3}(1-u^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm du.$

Next, we perform another substitution: let $u=\sin t$ and $\mathrm du=\cos t \mathrm dt$

$3\int u^{-3}(1-u^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm du=3\int {\sin^{-3} t}(1-{\sin}^{2} t)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cos t\mathrm dt=3\int {\sin^{-3} t}({\cos}^{2} t)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cos t\mathrm dt$

$=3\int {\sin^{-3} t} \,{\cos}^{2} t\mathrm dt=3\int \frac{\cos^2t}{\sin^3 t} \mathrm dt=3\int {\cot^2t} \,{\csc t} \mathrm dt$

We can use the identity $\csc^2 t-1= \cot^2 t.$

$3\int {\cot^2t} \,{\csc t} \mathrm dt=3\int (\csc^2 t-1)\csc t \mathrm dt=3\int \csc^3 t-\csc t  \mathrm dt=3\int \csc^3 t \mathrm dt- \int \csc t  \mathrm dt.$

For the second term use the fact that $\int \csc t \mathrm dt =-\log|\csc t+\cot t| \mathrm dt+C$

For the first term, use the reduction formula $$\int \csc^m t \mathrm dt= \frac{(-\cos t)(\csc^{m-1} t)}{m-1}+\frac{m-2}{m-1}\int \csc^{m-2} t \mathrm dt$$

with m=3.

Then, substitute back for $t$ and $u$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I believe $ \ dx \ = \ 3 \ u^2 \ du \ $ , no?